# How can I override a function in a different "class"?

Tags: actionscript-3, function, overriding

I'm trying to make a wrapper for another program, where I load the program and then intercept certain things and change them around, without actually changing the source code of the program and repackaging it. I want to be able to override a specific function, but it isn't declared within a class or package (so I can't extend the class and inherit it), and it isn't stored in variable form (so I can't just say object.functionName = newFunction). How can I do this?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to override the functionality of methods in a compiled SWF.  You can extend a class and override methods inside your own class, but the compiled SWF will continue to call the original methods on the original class.

Answer (score 0):

Use a proxy class to intercept function call [(here an exemple)](http://ltslashgt.com/2008/01/24/proxy-class-as3/).

Comment: I'm not certain I made this clear enough. The function I want to override is not in a package and not in any class. Let's call it "sendMessage()". Normally, when the program calls "sendMessage()", it will send a message. I want to make it so that whenever the program calls "sendMessage()", it does something else, but without changing the source code.

Comment: Are you talking about a function that is in a separate ".as" file like getDescribeType() etc ?

Comment: Yes, it is in a separate .as file made by someone else.